# MySQL trigger Calcular diferencia de lectura anterior con lectura actual

Tags: mysql, trigger, cálculo-relacional

Tengo una tabla que es de lecturas de contadores, los campos son :

```
id_lecturas int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
fk_contadores int(10) unsigned NULL
fecha_lecturas datetime NULL
valor_lecturas decimal(10,3) NULL
diferencia_lecturas decimal(10,3) NULL
```

Cuando se inserta o modifica un registro, se rellenan todos los campos menos el de `diferencia_lecturas`.

El campo diferencia_lecturas necesito que se calcule respecto a la lectura anterior y creo que la mejor opción es un trigger.

He creado uno así, pero de da error:

```
TRIGGER `calc_difference_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `lecturas` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF NEW.valor_lecturas != OLD.valor_lecturas THEN
        UPDATE lecturas
        SET NEW.diferencia_lecturas = (NEW.valor_lecturas - IFNULL((
            SELECT L2.valor_lecturas 
            FROM lecturas AS L2 
            WHERE NEW.fk_contadores = L2.fk_contadores AND L2.fecha_lecturas < NEW.fecha_lecturas AND L2.id_lecturas != NEW.id_lecturas), 0))
        WHERE id_lecturas = NEW.id_lecturas;
    END IF;

END;
```

El error es:

> You can't specify target table `lecturas` for update in FROM clause

¿Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te está dando porque en una sentencia `UPDATE` no puedes modificar un campo sobre una tabla si en la propia sentencia update estás accediendo sobre la misma tabla. (Esto podría generar problemas de bucles de updates sobre la tabla y echar abajo tu BD).

Deberías tomar una solución que pasase por seleccionar el valor que quieres de la tabla lecturas antes de llegar a actualizarla.

Algo del estilo:

```
-- Primero obtenemos el dato para actualizar la tabla
SELECT 
(NEW.valor_lecturas - IFNULL((
            SELECT L2.valor_lecturas 
            FROM lecturas AS L2 
            WHERE NEW.fk_contadores = L2.fk_contadores AND L2.fecha_lecturas < NEW.fecha_lecturas AND L2.id_lecturas != NEW.id_lecturas), 0)) into @varParaHacerUpdate FROM lectura
        WHERE id_lecturas = NEW.id_lecturas;

-- Y una vez tienes el valor para actualizar la sentencia update
UPDATE lecturas
        SET NEW.diferencia_lecturas = @varParaHacerUpdate
        WHERE id_lecturas = NEW.id_lecturas;
```

Comment: Gracias por la rápida respuesta. Lo probaré.